# Example of a disconnected manifold where the tangent space is not the dimension of the manifold?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Wikipedia says that the tangent spaces of a connected manifold all have the same dimension, equal to that of the manifold.

Well, is there an example of a simple disconnected manifold that doesn't have this property?

All I can think of is taking $[0,1]$ and $[2,3]$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$. Well, first of all, does the tangent space even exist at $0,1,2,3$? I can see that the set of "virtual velocities" are only in one direction at these points. Hence, this does not constitute a linear space. Is it a tangent space then?

If it is a tangent space, its dimension would still be 1, as the closed half-line of $\mathbb{R}$, so I am failing to find a good counterexample.

Comment: See the appropriate section from Lee's *Intro. to Smooth Manifolds*: https://books.google.at/books?id=w4bhBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA73&lpg=PA73&dq=tangent+space+manifold+with+boundary&source=bl&ots=FnnGjQSMMz&sig=EixS_2XXGnqGgsX6lFwRpK4ZmJ0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjx-qfb_afMAhXFjSwKHcHIAEcQ6AEIKTAC#v=onepage&q=tangent%20space%20manifold%20with%20boundary&f=false

Comment: Some people require manifolds to be of pure dimension even if disconnected. Others allow the different components to have different dimension. In the latter case, the dimension of the tangent space depends on the point.

Comment: Take the disjoint union of a line and plane.

Comment: You're talking about manifolds *with boundary* with $[0,1]$, etc., and there is still a $1$-dimensional tangent space at the boundary points. But that's a different kettle of fish.

Answer (score 2):

Just to close the question: You can take a disjoint union of two manifolds of different dimensions. Some people see this space as a manifold.